# Favicon NOT working on Edge

Tags: html, icons, microsoft-edge, favicon

I have a problem with this favicon I generated for a local server php project. It works fine on most browsers (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Opera) but on Microsoft Edge it doesn't work (It shows the default tab favicon).

I've tried many solutions to this problem like clearing the cache, using image format (.png) instead of icon (.ico), but nothing seemed to work.

Here are the lines of code that I've included in the HTML head:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Anyone had the same issue and solved it?

Comment: Did you check the actual HTML code with "View Source" on Edge? Although declaring `favicon.ico` two times can sound "safer", maybe this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: I checked it but nothing strange I've seen. And I've tried using only the shortcut icon, it didn't work either.

Comment: What's the aspect ratio of your icon?

Comment: is it still issue or solved ? try the online fevicon generator and gt the image with .ico extention and use that in for favicon

Answer (score 59):

For me the problem was that on localhost it never worked in Edge. No matter what I did. It was always fine in Chrome and Firefox. The solution was that it only worked in Edge after I deployed to the webserver.

Comment: **Note**: Try to make the path of image absolute instead of relative, which worked for me!

Comment: Making the path absolute doesn't work if the host ultimately resolves to a loopback IP address e.g. 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 18):

There are 2 problems in Edge. Both are avoided when deploying to a web server (that's why it started working in another answers after deploying to a web server). However, you can make it work on localhost, too.

**1. Incomplete headers returned from server**

It looks like for Edge the web server has to return Cache-Control header for the favicon.

E.g. this value works:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
```

The common web servers probably send that header automatically. However, if you have some custom solution, you have to implement it manually. E.g. in WCF:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=2592000");
```

**2. Edge cannot access localhost because of some Windows security settings**

By default, Windows store apps cannot use loopback interface. This seems to affect favicon loading, which is loaded using another means that the web page alone (so, even if the web page works, favicon does not work).

To enable loopback for Edge, run this in PowerShell as Administrator:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

Edge restart is not needed - after page refresh (F5), the favicon should be loaded.

To disable loopback again:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -d -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

The favicon will be cached in Edge, so it will be still visible.

**Other info**

If you use HTTPS, it looks like the certificate has to be valid (trusted) for the favicon to show.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue with Edge. I have tried a lot of workarounds, but only moving the icon from local to www server was successful.
If your server is local (at localhost), try to move the icon file to a global server.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Basically, I solved the problem like you: just add an absolute global http-address. Then it works. relative path do not work.

Comment: Yes, Edge doesn't like relative paths. It expects the favicon to be on the server root.

Comment: Relative path, server root etc. is possibly a red-herring. Ultimately if the icon host resolves to a loopback IP address (e.g. 127.0.0.1) Edge/IE11 won't load it.

Answer (score 4):

You should change the name of your favicon.ico file. Like "myFavicon.ico".

You should also add `?` at the end of your link, like so:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/favicon.ico?" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/favicon.ico?" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Also, did you refresh the cache before testing? If not, reset the cache, or you will not see your changes.

Finally, it could also be your icon. Try using a [favicon generator](http://www.favicon-generator.org/).

Comment: Changing the favicon's filename worked for me. Weird.

Answer (score 4):

for me i added   id="favicon"

the whole line looks  like

```html
    <link  id="favicon" href="~/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"  />
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not seem to work either. It seemed to after I loaded (and cached) the icon from an external source, then changed the link tag to include the ID. When I attempted the same fix on another system running Edge, it simply would not work.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for EDGE**

---

**TL;DR;**

Host your favicon images externally.

---

If you don't have a favicon already, you can generate them [here](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) or [here](http://www.favicomatic.com/).

I have uploaded my 32x32 png to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com)
It works during local testing **only** **if** the favicon/png image is hosted **!externally!**, like `imgur.com`.

In the `head` of the page I set the favicon like this:

```
 <link href="https://i.imgur.com/xxxx32x32.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

There is no naming convention, you can name the favicon whatever you like `xyz.png` but I guess it has to be 32x32!

I have also setup a `hosts` entry pointing to my web app in IIS like:

```
127.0.0.1   www.your-app.com
```

**Steps:** **Close the browser, wait 30 seconds and reopen it**.

Enter your url either like:
`www.your-app.com` or 
`localhost/yourApp` or 
`localhost:xxxx/yourApp`.

Try both!

**Make sure you clear the cache. Hit F5. Probably you need to repeat this steps, two to three times.**

It will take some time for Edge to grasp it.

This works in IIS. After that I have tested it wit IIS Express and it works there too. It doesn't matter. What matters is, **you have to host the favicon externally**.

[image]
For example, IE11 does not show favicons at all, no matter which site I visit.
So, forget about IE11 ;-)

Comment: I uploaded my favicon to my webserver and everything now is displaying as it should. I also created a manifest.json file, uploaded all of the icons contained in the json file to my webserver, updated all of the urls, and now when i pin the website from Edge it will display the icons in the Tile.  I'd say this is the best solution to just drop all icons and favicons onto an external webserver.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your favicon is too big. According to the answer in the thread in this link should a favicon be 16 x 16 px:
https://forum.yola.com/yola/topics/edge-not-displaying-favicon

In my website (loekbergman.nl) is it working and I have a 16x16px icon indeed.

Answer (score 1):

First, try the usual fixing method: clear cache, history and cookies.

If that doesn't work, try:

```
<html>    
<head>
<title> Your Title</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body> Your content </body>
</html>
```

Make sure favicon.ico is in the **same** folder as your html file.

If it still doesn't work, it might be an issue with MS Edge. Check the website below:
https://www.wix.com/support/html5/ugc/b4b4a8f2-217d-4e25-aa55-00c19f5d5fc4/1a8ee7cd-3092-42e8-9078-dc528f8bfc87

Answer (score 1):

Adding **Cache-Control:public, max-age=14400** to the http header worked for me. Checked it with IE, Edge, and Chrome on Windows 10 using an ESP8266-12E running Arduino as a web server on a local network. (Haven't tried any Apple or Android-specific support yet). FWIW - Here's part of the html from the root page of my server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Favicon Test</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/faviconS.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link id="favicon-16x16" rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link id="favicon-32x32" rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link id="favicon-96x96" rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

and here's a ESP8266/Arduino code snippet for creating the http header in the response and sending the icon data previously stored as a file using SPIFFS.

```
...
f = SPIFFS.open("/favicon.ico", "r");
if (!f) {
  Serial.println("file open failed");
} else {
  Serial.println("favicon.ico open succeeded...");
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.print("Content-Length:");
  client.println(String(f.size()));
  client.println("Content-Type:image/x-icon");
  client.println("Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400");
  client.println();  // blank line indicates end of header
  while (f.available()) {  // send the binary for the icon
    byte b = f.read();
    client.write(b);
  }
f.close();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Image name should be favicon.ico and format should be ico
2. Place the ico in "wwwroot" folder
3. ico reference in index.html should be

   "< link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" >"
4. Edge doesn't show favicon while running from local. Deploy in webserver and try

This worked for me

Comment: This post fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a echo **encapsulation** issue.
I mean that href would have "request->baseUrl;" as a value

try

```
  <?php
      echo '<link rel="icon" href="'.Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />';
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your participation. Tried everything you guys wrote, but it did not solve my problem. I need a more credible source, a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and how I have solved as below.

- Icon name must be `favicon`. I have used `.ico`. (Different name was not working for me)
- Favicon must be at the root folder where your `HTML` located. (Below is my folder structure)

  ```
  -- src
     -- app
        -- images
        -- css
        -- favicon.ico
        -- index.html
  ```
- include icon in HTML

  ```
  <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  ```

> I have tested and fixed my issue in below browsers
>
> - Chrome (Version 76.0.3809.100)
> - Firefox (Version 68.0.1)
> - Safari (Version 11.1)
> - Internet Explorer (Version 11 &10)
> - Edge (Version 42.17134.1.0)

Comment: I think you're solution is by relative path, which I don't think it works. 
Since you say the favicon should be at the root folder (server root) `href="favicon.ico` should be enouth, and this is acceptable by Edge.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question, so thought I'd post an update. It now works even in Edge, as long as "favicon.ico" is located on the root, i.e. `/favicon.ico`.

But the issue still appears to exist, if the favicon is placed elsewhere besides the root, and included with a relative path. I saw my favicon on Firefox and Opera, but not in Edge.

However, the solution is much simpler now. As hinted by a comment from @Rui Lopes, using an **absolute address** worked for me, even with a localhost. I first tried my internal IP (not the loopback) and it showed up. But it also works with something like:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://localhost:8000/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

By the way, I'm simply using the `python3 -m http.server` for now. I have Edge *Version 92.0.902.73 (Official build) (64-bit)*.

The simplest solution, of course is to just add the "favicon.ico" to the web server root. And based on my observation, the `<link>` code is not even needed. I saw the following request on the server log, even without the code:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Aug/2021 18:38:40] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Tested with Edge, Firefox, Opera and Chrome, and they all seem to do this by default. I have not checked any reference or documentation for this though, so I'd still recommend adding the HTML `<link>` for it.

Answer (score -2):

Try creating a 512x512 in PNG format. Worked for me.