# Favicon in EDGE

Tags: html, wordpress, favicon

**I don't think this should be treated as a duplicate since [the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081965/favicon-not-working-on-edge) didn't get a proper answer**

I have a WP page running and for some reason I can't get Edge to display the favicon. It works everywhere, even in IE11. The first two lines are mine, the others are generated by WP. I doesn't work on deployed server either.

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://192.168.1.59/wp-content/uploads/logo.jpg" sizes="32x32" />
```

Comment: From what I know making themes for shops, WP should generate favicons and You just need to include it in theme root path as .ico and .png.  I just check my latest blog and favicon works. Try to clear browser cache cause favicons are often do not show right away and sometimes clearing cache do not help and You need to reload page few times.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Clearing cache doesn't help. I remember setting up favicon in the theme settings. Is there anything else i can do?

Comment: Sorry, I have .ico and .png in images folder and it always work. But as I said, favicons are strange, they always show when You first time open Your site, but when You change it they are overwritten after sometime, not right away.

Comment: The problem was using jpg in wordpress as icon instead of png or ico. Thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 3):

Please try

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

> Note : MS Edge won't display favicon for locally hosted sites.