# Favicon do not shown in Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, microsoft-edge

I`m working on SharePoint online site collection. I declared my favicon in master page file by:

```
        <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="https://spellabs.sharepoint.com/sites/translom/PortalPages/assets/favicons/favicon.ico?rev=45" />
```

And it works fine with all other browser except: MS Edge and IE. But favicon.ico is present in downloaded files:

[image]

How to deal with it?

Comment: please try to make a test using your HTML code to check whether you are able to see the favicon or not. Further, Try to add type="image/x-icon" in your HTML code for testing. Currently I am not available with SharePoint to make a test with it. I will try to do it. You can also try to refer this thread may give you some more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081965/favicon-not-working-on-edge

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT `type="image/x-icon"` didnt help. I guess that only external source can fix this Edge issue. I have to store my favicon, for example, on imgur.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT also i`ve noticed that `favicon` placed inside `/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=26"/` working in Edge as well,  but this solution is not what im looking for. I need to store favicon in site assets, not virtual directory.