# Why does my Edge favicon not work whereas the it does on Chrome?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I have a simple block of html running on a local Windows PC

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>FavIcon Test</title>
    <link id='favicon' rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/>
</head>
<body style='margin-left:10px'>
    Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

I have grabbed a random website favicon file* and saved it to the same location as the html and have run it in Chrome and in Edge; Chrome shows me the expected site-icon, whereas Edge fails to show it.

What is going on?

Thanks
Abe

*e.g. go to https://ico.org.uk/favicon.ico and then right click on the result to [Save Image As...]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081965/favicon-not-working-on-edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The favicon won't show on Edge Legacy in local server due to **incomplete headers returned from server** and **Edge cannot access localhost because of some Windows security settings**. For detailed information you coulde refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081965/favicon-not-working-on-edge/48078478#48078478).

The issue will be fixed if you deploy the site to a web server or using an absolute global http-address favicon href. The following code will work on Edge Legacy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>FavIcon Test</title>
    <link id='favicon' rel='icon' href='https://ico.org.uk/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />
</head>
<body style='margin-left:10px'>
    Hello World
</body>
</html>
```